# index 400 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 368

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

im trying to build a face recognition model using CNN i have an image dataset that consists of 368 classes each class contains 15 images . im trying to use keras.utils.to_categorical on the image labels(class names which are numbers from 1-368 ) to set a specific label to 1 while set the others to zero during training.here is what i have done so far

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from pathlib import Path
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
SEED = 44000
data = []
label = []
BASE_FOLDER = r'C:\Users\Desktop\images\\'
folders = os.listdir(BASE_FOLDER)
for folder in folders:
      for file in os.listdir(BASE_FOLDER + folder + '//'):
          img = cv2.imread(BASE_FOLDER + folder + '//' + file)
          data.append(img)
          label.append(folder)


train_data, test_data, train_label, test_label = train_test_split(data, label, test_size=0.1, random_state=SEED)

train_data = np.array(train_data, dtype=np.float32)

test_data = np.array(test_data, dtype=np.float32)
train_data = train_data / 180 # to make the array values between 0-1. image size is 180 X 180
test_data = test_data / 180
train_label = list(map(int, train_label))
train_label = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_label, 368)
```

but i am getting this error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-f087078ef22a> in <module>
----> 1 train_label = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_label, 368)
~\Miniconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py in to_categorical(y, num_classes, dtype)
 32     n = y.shape[0]
 33     categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes), dtype=dtype)
 ---> 34     categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
 35     output_shape = input_shape + (num_classes,)
 36     categorical = np.reshape(categorical, output_shape)
 IndexError: index 400 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 368
```

whats the meaning of this error and how to solve it ?

Comment: What is your question? Please be specific. Posting code and an error message is not asking a question. See [ask].

Comment: Are you sure you only have 368 categories and does "train_label" is labeled from 0 to 367?

Comment: @Mark.F  that was the issue i was specifying a wrong number of the categories . also the "train_label" were labeled according to image class name .i updated it and now it works. thanks